# Converting ARMA models to infinite AR process in R

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive, arma

I'm trying to recreate some test statistics that use the infinite AR representation of normal ARMA models. I found out about the function ARMAtoMA but have not been able to find the same functionality for AR representations as well. Do you guys know of a package that would make extracting them easy? I was hopeful when I found the ARMAtoMA package, because it allows for such easy implementation in iterative loops, so I kind of dread having to implement this by hand.

Found the incredibly easy solution in this forum post: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/8578-A-question-about-ARMAtoMA

You just have to switch up the PHI and THETA in the ARMAtoMA module to get the PIs of the infinite AR process. I guess I just didn't think this through correctly.